# CLion on Windows has problem with intrinsics defined as a macro

Tags: c++, clion, intrinsics, icc

When using Intel compiler, CLion complains that `_mm_extract_epi64` may be undeclared or unknown (still compilation is successful). On the other hand CLion doesn't complain on some other intrinsics functions such as `_mm_set_epi64x`.

The difference is that the former is defined as a macro.

```cpp
#define _mm_extract_epi64(X, N)                                                \
  ((long long)__builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2di((__v2di)(__m128i)(X), (int)(N)))
```

while the latter is defined as an inline function

```cpp
static __inline__ __m128i __DEFAULT_FN_ATTRS _mm_set_epi64x(long long __q1,
                                                            long long __q0) {
  return __extension__(__m128i)(__v2di){__q0, __q1};
}
```

CLion doesn't think that `__builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2di` is a valid builtin function.

Same error occurs for MinGW gcc because of the same reason. Only MSVC doesn't complain because `_mm_extract_epi64` is defined as `extern`.

Is there any fix?

Comment: Does clion know that you have SSE4.1 available?

Comment: @chtz I think so. Codes like `_mm_minpos_epu16(_mm_setzero_si128())` work

Comment: You tagged this ICC; ICC and MSVC let you use intrinsics without enabling ISA extensions for them.  So `phminposuw` doesn't prove you enabled SSE4.1.  But with ICC you wouldn't need to.  Anyway, https://godbolt.org/z/acjEMrzTh shows ICC 2021.7.1 on Linux (on Godbolt) compiles `_mm_extract_epi64(v, 1);` just fine even in 32-bit mode, but that GCC only defines it in 64-bit mode.  IDK about older ICC or an install that might be using different headers.